# CentOS OpenSSL php_openssl.dll not found

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, centos

I get this error every now and then on my websites. After some Googling, I noticed that Linux doesn't support .dll files - but how do I get rid of this message?

Full error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like php_openssl.dll was being included from my php.ini, I commented this line out and it works!